# c++ abstract class copy constructor call makes error

Tags: c++, abstract-class, copy-constructor

My question is very similar like other's, but a bit different. I have a sample code:

```
class B1 {
private :
    int * ptr;
public:
    B1() : a{ 1 } { ptr = new int{ 2 }; }
    B1(const B1& other) : a{ other.a } { ptr = new int{ *other.ptr }; }
    ~B1() { delete ptr; }
    int a;
    virtual void smthing() = 0;
};
class D : B1 {
public:
    D(int i) : B1{} {}
    D(const D& a) : B1{ a } {}
    void smthing() { return; };
};
int main() {
    D d { 3 };
    D dd { d };
    return 0;
}
```

I am using vs2015, and this code is works, but gives me error: object of abstract class type "B1" is not allowed...
If I remove this line `D(const D& a) : B1{ a } {}`, the base class copy constructor is called and there's no problem, but if I need the derived class copy constructor how can I make this work without error?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This code should be valid... Are you sure that this is a compilation error and not an Intelli Sense error?

Comment: I think you simplified the problem too much when you created your example  that you left out the code that caused the error. This code compiles on ideone: https://ideone.com/ysf6I5

Comment: You should put `public` when deriving from `B1`  -- `class D : public B1`

Comment: @gchen Why do they need to do that?

Comment: @gchen Not necessary. Even it `B1` is inherited privately it should compile fine.

Comment: "and this code is works, but gives me error" how is that possible?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with gcc, clang, or msvs 2017.  If this code is not compiling with msvs 2015 I suspect it is a compiler bug.

Comment: If I give -- class D : public B1 -- to the code, the error is still present, and yes its running, I just got the error

Comment: Compile this exact code shown and provide actual error messages, not your interpretation of it (including line numbers).

Comment: @VTT yes you sure its intelisense error, but why is it there?

Comment: Intelisense does have false positives. Although I would not have expected it to fail with this code.

Comment: It is a bug in Visual Studio. [I've already submitted a bug report last year](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/165311/vs2017-155-c-intellisense-incorrectly-displays-err.html).

Comment: okay, thank you guys for the fast react, i need to delete this post or what can i do now?

Comment: virtual void smthing() = 0; defines B1 as being purey virtual, meaning it can not be instantiated

Comment: @138 the problem here is Intellisense wrongly complains even though B1 is not instantiated.